# aside default allocator, does stl has other allocators now?

Tags: c++, stl

Stl default allocator, defined in allocator.h, is a simple wrapper of new, delete operator. Does stl has some other allocators, for example, memory-pool based allocator? If it has, which head file it is defined.

I explored the stl source code(4.1.1) and googled it, but can find anything.

Comment: Default allocator always use `new` and `delete` and there are no memory-pool or similar other allocation until C++11. Default allocators are very basic stateless allocators.

Comment: There's the polymorphic allocator in the library fundamentals TS.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding whether the standard library supplies more allocator templates than `std::allocator` (disregarding the wrapper `std::scoped_allocator_adapter`), searching through the C++11 PDF didn't find any.

---

In other non-news…

The STL, the `Standard Template Library`, is *not the same as the C++ standard library*. The STL started as an Ada library (IIRC), developed by Stepanov. Stepanov and Stroustrup jointly proposed inclusion of most of the C++ version of STL into the standard library of the first C++ standardization, in 1998, and it was adopted. This part of the standard library is mainly about the iterators and algorithms.

Perusing the source code of some standard library implementation is not a good way to establish what functionality is standard. For that, the relevant standard is the authoritative source. But also sites like [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=allocator) can be useful.